# Set bounds on plotly express choropleth color scale

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I'd like to set the bounds on a choropleth map in plotly express, e.g. such that this map goes from 0 to 5 instead of 1 to 100. Is this possible?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"state": ["CA", "OR"], "val": [1, 100]})

fig = px.choropleth(locations=df.state,
                    locationmode="USA-states",
                    color=df.val,
                    scope="usa")
fig.show()
```

([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kSBzjOJiQT8M63fI3SKlncnajuIYsJjR?usp=sharing))
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the `range_color` arg:

```
fig = px.choropleth(locations=df.state,
                    locationmode="USA-states",
                    color=df.val,
                    scope="usa",
                    range_color=(0,5))
fig.show()
```

[image]